# SSIS: import to xlsx. How to replace dots with commas?

Tags: excel, ssis

I have SSIS package, which imports data from sql database to excel. Dataflow is the following:
OLE DB Source > Data Conversion > Excel Destiantion

Excel to where I import data have sum fromula to sum together one cell values, but as there are currently numbers with dots like 4532.34 then it will not work. If I press ctrl+H and replace . > , then it works. I have tried different ways to get those values with commas from db, tired to format excel, tried convert into different data types with Data Conversion task, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you want to treat it as a string but this would work.

derived column:

```
replace((DT_STR,50,1252)columnName , ".",",")
```

You are casting as a string and then replacing periods with commas.

Comment: Tried to add Derived Column task after Data Conversion task, but it did not work out for me, in excel I still got dots. I added above code into Expression field.  After Conversion, data type is DT_NUMERIC.

Comment: This gets rid of the data conversion. Is your source numeric in the ole db?

Comment: Got this replacing part to work, when I first convert data numeric to string, but yes this is not expected, because with this approach excel formulas still not work as numbers are stored as text.